# Integral with goniometric functions

Tags: integration

I am learning on an exam and found this example:

$\int cos^3x sinx dx =$

How do determine it here? Do I need to apply here some goniometric rules? And with substitution?

Thank you

Comment: Let $u=\cos x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \cos(ax) = -a \sin(ax)
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
I &= \int\cos^{m}(ax) \, \sin(ax) \, dx \\
&= \int \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{-1}{a(m+1)} \cos^{m+1}(ax) \right] dx \\
&= \frac{-1}{a(m+1)} \cos^{m+1}(ax).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$ \int (f(x))^n f'(x)dx = \frac{(f(x))^{n+1}}{n+1}+C.$$

Comment: Ohh, the formula looks even more scary than the example in the OP

Comment: @user2932090: It is very very useful!